# Installing mysql in PyCharm community edition

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, mysql-python

I wasn't able to find this question asked before and this is driving me crazy. If this question is a duplicate, I'd appreciate it if someone could point me to an answer.

I tried to install mysql (using `pip install mysql`) in the PyCharm terminal using Python 3.6. This is the error I get. I already updated pip to the latest version.

> Command "C:\Users\David\PycharmProjects\cryptocurrency2\cryptocurrencytrading\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-alqyprfu\mysqlclient\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**f
>   ile**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-gcaxj074\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\David\PycharmProjects\cryptocurrency2\cryptocurrencytrading\include\site\python3.6\mysqlclient" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-alqyprfu\mysqlclient\
>   You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
>   You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: Hi, did you try what it suggested? Upgrading pip to a more recent version:  'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' ?

Comment: What you show is not an error but an advise. The actual error seems to be cut off from your output.

Comment: edited to include full error. As for pip, the latest version is already installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can install python packages in PyCharm without pip by using their package manager. Please refer to their official docs about installing packages [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html)

or you can also always use your OS cmd to install the packages explicitly.

I'd suggest you should update your pip version by :

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Hope this Helps!

Comment: `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\david\pycharmprojects\cryptocurrency2\cryptocurrencytrading\lib\site-packages (18.1)`

Comment: have you tried installing it with your os default terminal? is it giving same error?

Answer (score -1):

try to use `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`
ur pip version is too low

Comment: `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\david\pycharmprojects\cryptocurrency2\cryptocurrencytrading\lib\site-packages (18.1)`